# I have make a webage on tailwind but when i run it on wamp server the tailwind doesnt get show up

Tags: html, css, frameworks, wamp

I have install tailwind using npm and it works fine with vscode.

My Wamp server works fine too ,I have inserted data into database using wamp before but when it comes to tailwind it doesn't get show up right.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbcje.png)
What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure tailwind correctly?
**tailwind.config.js**
**src/input.css**
and after that did you run this command?
`npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch`

then did you import css file in your working file?

Comment: Yes , I have configure it correctly , tailwind utilities classes are running correctly but when I put html , css file in wamp "www" folder in order to work -- Tailwind doesn't get showed up.

Comment: Then I will suggest you to check if the paths are actually working correctly. If configuration is working fine, there should not be any problem. 

Or another suggestion: Create new project on your wamp server's www directory. then configure tailwind there. I hope it will work fine.